OOMKilled, Rabbitmq pod is not being ready
I've Installed bitnami RabbitMQ using helm charts. The pod status is CrashLoopBackOff, the pod is not being ready, the reason is OOMKilled for rabbitmq container.
Although I have set
 resourcesPreset: "nano"
  volumePermissions:
   resources:
     requests:
       cpu: 0.1
       memory: 64Mi
     limits:
       cpu: 0.5
       memory: 128Mi
  ##

in values.yaml and
type: "relative"
   value: "10%"

I get
Limits:
      cpu:                375m
      ephemeral-storage:  1Gi
      memory:             384Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:                250m
      ephemeral-storage:  50Mi
      memory:             256Mi

when I describe the pod. I am not sure if the OOMKilled happens because of the above parameters, but if so, could you advise what should be done to make the parameters changed, because I do not find any other option for those parameters in values.yaml file. What defaults are being used here? And is OOMKilled  happening for other reason?
Thank you

I set all my resourcesPreset to none (not nano).  Then if I require any specific setting, I put that in the resources: {} block.
resourcesPreset: "none"

I set all my resourcesPreset to none (not nano).  Then if I require any specific setting, I put that in the resources: {} block.
resourcesPreset: "none"
